# Flutter onesignal App Delegate Proxy is disabled

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, onesignal

I have implement onesignal on my flutter app on android its working fine. But on ios its showing these errors.

```
[GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001011] App Delegate Proxy is disabled.

 WARNING: OneSignal has detected that your application delegate implements a deprecated method (application:didReceiveLocalNotification:). Please note that this method has been officially deprecated and the OneSignal SDK will no longer call it. You should use UNUserNotificationCenter instead
```

I have check certificate, Identifiers, keys etc all is fine.

This is my notificationservice.swift file

```
import UserNotifications

import OneSignal

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var receivedRequest: UNNotificationRequest!
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.receivedRequest = request
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        self.bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            //If your SDK version is < 3.5.0 uncomment and use this code:
            /*
            OneSignal.didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: self.bestAttemptContent)
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
            */
            
            /* DEBUGGING: Uncomment the 2 lines below to check this extension is excuting
                          Note, this extension only runs when mutable-content is set
                          Setting an attachment or action buttons automatically adds this */
            //OneSignal.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE, visualLevel: .LL_NONE)
            //bestAttemptContent.body = "[Modified] " + bestAttemptContent.body
            
            OneSignal.didReceiveNotificationExtensionRequest(self.receivedRequest, with: bestAttemptContent, withContentHandler: self.contentHandler)
        }
    }
}
```

Appdelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import UserNotifications
// import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
            print(userInfo)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And pod onesignal version

```
target 'DorNotifExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 3.4.3', '< 4.0'
end
```

I try everything copy paste code of official document code on notificationservice.swift file but no progress its keep showing error of AppDelegate. I try wifi switch, try to upload app on testflight then check But the status Apns Delegate Never Fired is not changing in onesignal user.

Issue i found is Firebase_auth if i comment this line in appdelegate

let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

Then notification is working fine but the phone auth stop working. I have searched but don't get how to manage these together.